# How do I compare names in the previous row of a dataframe column while grouping by a unique ID in another column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, fuzzywuzzy

I have the following table:

| Unique ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | Mayank |
| 111 | Mayanak |
| 222 | Leddie . |
| 222 | Leddie Chan |
| 333 | May BOU KARAM |
| 333 | May Bou Karam |

I'm trying to compare each row in the 'Name' column to its previous column while grouping by Unique ID. Expecting an output similar to:

| Unique ID | Name | Name2 | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Mayank | Mayanak | 67 |
| 111 | Mayanak | nan | 67 |
| 222 | Leddie . | Leddie Chan | 90 |
| 222 | Leddie Chan | nan | 90 |
| 333 | May BOU KARAM | May Bou Karam | 90 |
| 333 | May Bou Karam | nan | 33 |

I've used the following code to evaluate the score of one row compared to its next row but I can't figure out how to group it by the Unique ID:

```
df['Name2'] = df['Name'].shift(-1)
df['Score'] = df.apply(lambda x: fuzz.partial_ratio(x['Name'], x['Name2']), axis=1)
```

I get the following output:

| Unique ID | Name | Name2 | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Mayank | Mayanak | 67 |
| 111 | Mayanak | Leddie . | 0 |
| 222 | Leddie . | Leddie Chan | 100 |
| 222 | Leddie Chan | May BOU KARAM | 18 |
| 333 | May BOU KARAM | May Bou Karam | 90 |
| 333 | May Bou Karam | nan | 33 |

I'm not married to using fuzz.partial_ratio to match the strings. If there's a better way to match the strings, I'd be game for that.

Also, I realise that the Name2 column is not necessary, but I created it to make sure I'm getting each step right. Apologies if it's confusing. Any help and feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `df['Name2'] = df.groupby('Unique ID')['Name'].shift(-1)`

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len() gets returned from the df['Test'] = df.apply(lambda x: fuzz.partial_ratio(x['Name'], x['Name2']), axis=1) line

Comment: That's the error you got from `fuzz.partial_ratio(x['name'], x['Name2'])` because `x['Name2']` is `nan`, which is a float. replace `shift(-1)` with `shift(-1, fill_value='')`.